# Flask: index() returns render_template(...) . Why does return index() not work?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Using Flask.  This must be a basic gotcha I just don't know about.

I have two templates, `index.html` and `index8.html`

`index()` sets `url` to one of these two strings, based on a session parameter, and returns `render_template(url, data={...})`

Then I've got a `toggleMode()` which sets the session parameter (from a POST), and then calls `return index()`

It *does* seem to run the `index()` code... it prints out `index.html` or `index8.html` correctly, which is passed to render_template, and returned, and returned... but it never uses `index8.html`.

If you change html template files, do you need a redirect? Is that it?

Why does Flask not change templates, in this situation?  I'm printing the template name, and it is `'index8.html'` passed in to `render_template`.  But it still renders as though I had passed in `'index.html'`. (Or, rather, it doesn't do a new render, at all, despite Flask returning a 200 reply to `toggleMode()`)

EDIT:

Ok minimal example...

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
   
    try:
        mode = session['MODE'] == "Four"
    except:
        session['MODE'] = "Four"
        mode = True

    
    print ('index.html' if mode else 'index8.html')

    url4 = 'index.html'
    url8 = 'index8.html'

    return render_template(url4 if mode else url8, data={...})

@app.route('/toggleMode', methods=['POST'])
def toggle_mode():
    data = request.get_json()
    print (data)
    session['MODE'] = data[0]['mode']
    print(session['MODE'])
    return index()
```

I get the correct `index.html` or `index8.html` printed out, but toggling the mode always renders with `index.html`

Comment: Please make this a [mcve].

Comment: I would but I'm developing over ssh in vim, in ubuntu terminal, and I can't copy paste from my terminal. I've tried CTRL+C, I've tried CTRL+SHIFT+C.  I'd have to ask a new question to solve that first :(

Comment: That seems like a solveable problem if you want help: copy your file locally, open it in a text editor, and *then* copy the text

Comment: `toggle_mode()` isn't a true toggle; it depends on the input data.  What input data are you sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code seems to work as designed. If I wrap it in a little extra code to make it runnable (it helps if you do this when posting questions), so that we have:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

# I'm faking a session with a global variable here.
session = {}


@app.route("/")
def index():
    try:
        mode = session["MODE"] == "Four"
    except:
        session["MODE"] = "Four"
        mode = True

    url4 = "index.html"
    url8 = "index8.html"

    if mode:
        return f"mode is True, use {url4}\n"
    else:
        return f"mode is False, use {url8}\n"


@app.route("/toggleMode", methods=["POST"])
def toggle_mode():
    data = request.get_json()
    session["MODE"] = data[0]["mode"]
    return index()
```

I see the following behavior:

1. An initial request to `/` uses `index.html` (because there is no
   `MODE` in `session`, which trigger a `KeyError` so we hit the
   `except` block).

   ```
   $ curl localhost:5000
   mode is True, use index.html
   ```
2. We make a request to `/toggleMode` with `mode` set to anything
   other than `Four:

   ```
   $ curl -H content-type:application/json -d '[{"mode": "Three"}]' localhost:5000/toggleMode
   mode is False, use index8.html
   ```

   This returns to `index()`, which uses `index8.html` because the
   condition `session["MODE"] == "Four"` is `False`.
3. A request to `/` shows that the session change was persistent; the
   condition is still `False`:

   ```
   $ curl localhost:5000
   mode is False, use index8.html
   ```
4. We make a request to `/toggleMode` with `mode` set to `Four`:

   ```
   $ curl -H content-type:application/json -d '[{"mode": "Four"}]' localhost:5000/toggleMode
   mode is True, use index.html
   ```

   With this change, `index()` is once again using `index.html`.
5. ...and the change is persistent:

   ```
   $ curl localhost:5000
   mode is True, use index.html
   ```

If I replace this:

```
    if mode:
        return f"mode is True, use {url4}\n"
    else:
        return f"mode is False, use {url8}\n"
```

With this:

```
return render_template(url4 if mode else url8)
```

I continue to see the correct behavior: if I create files matching the two template names, they are used appropriately.

Comment: Bizarre.  Thanks for making the effort.  I wonder what it is then.  I'll let you know, when I work it out.

Comment: I'm just faking a session with a global dictionary, but if you're using some sort of client session have you verified that the stored value is changing when you expect it to?

Comment: Sorry, turned out I'm an idiot.  I was calling it with an ajax call.  switched to form/submit, and all good.